# How to set initial tab in react navigation TabNavigator dynamically

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-ios

I am using `react-navigation` and have a nested `TabNavigator` inside a `StackNavigator`. I have three tabs in `TabNavigator` and need to set `initialRouteName` for `TabNavigator` dynamically based on some logic.

I have tried putting the `TabNavigator` inside a `React` Component with dynamically selected initial tab and used in `StackNavigator` with passing props through `screenProps` of `TabNavigator`. But this way I am unable to navigate to any route of `StackNavigator`.

Is there any way to make `initialRouteName` dynamically.

Note: I am not using redux for this application.

Comment: Some related discussion here: https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/1089

Answer (score 10):

```
<Tab.Navigator
 initialRouteName="YOUR_TAB_NAME"
 ... 
/>
```

...

Reference:https://reactnavigation.org/docs/bottom-tab-navigator/#initialroutename

Full example:

```
const TabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator();

function MyTabNavigator(props) {
  const { initialRouteName } = props;
  return (
    <TabNavigator.Navigator initialRouteName={initialRouteName}>
      <TabNavigator.Screen name="Tab1" component={Tab1} />
      <TabNavigator.Screen name="Tab2" component={Tab2} />
      <TabNavigator.Screen name="Tab3" component={Tab3} />
    </TabNavigator.Navigator>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  const initialRouteName = someCondition ? 'Tab1' : 'Tab2';
  return (
    <StackNavigator.Navigator>
      <StackNavigator.Screen
        name="TabNavigator"
        component={MyTabNavigator}
        initialParams={{ initialRouteName }}
      />
      <StackNavigator.Screen name="OtherScreen" component={OtherScreen} />
    </StackNavigator.Navigator>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you were really close.
You can set the index of navigation state to specify which to be shown as an initial route.

```
<SomeTabNavigator
  navigation={{
    ...this.props.navigation,
    state: {
      ...this.props.navigation.state,
      index: 1 // or whichever you want
    }
  }}
  screenProps={{
    // whatever the props you wanna pass to child screens.
  }}
/>
```

But you also have to pass the router via static otherwise you cannot navigate. (or try using `navigate` not `push` with navigation if you already have this.)

```
class Screen extends React.Component{

  static router = SomeTabNavigator.router

...
```

If this isn't the case then you should check the structure of your navigator that you have right nesting of stack navigator and tab navigator.

Maybe it's too late, but I hope it will help someone.

Check the link below for more details.

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/custom-navigators.html